# How do I get a form element to display in a lightbox?

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I'm currently using Drupal 7 and I'm using the Form API to generate the form.  What I'd like is for certain fields to be represented by a link, which when clicked on, opens the field in some kind of lightbox.  This is what I tried, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
  $form['snvisdt_note']=array(
  '#prefix' => "<a href=\"/screen #snvisdt_note_div\" rel=\"lightmodal\" title=\"Add Note\" >note\</a> <div id=\"snvisdt_note_div\" style=\"display:none;\">",
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => 'Add More Information',
  '#suffix' => "</div>",
  );
```

"screen" is the name of the page the form is on.  I am trying to do this in Lightbox 2, but would be happy to use some other solution, if it works.  Can someone please give me an example of what would work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display `form` element into popup, then I would suggest you to use `ctools` api. It will provide you functionality to create a custom popup to render content.

> Ctools provide Modal dialog functionality to display element in modal.

You need to follow below step for the same:

- Create a custom module and create `Menu item` which will interact with `ctools modal`.
- Define `ajax callback` for the menu item and return HTML of the modal
  using ajax.

  You can check working example  (http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/insert-form-pop-modal-ctools-and-drupal-7)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create the whole form and for the field you need to open in lightbox you should add the `#prefix` property containing the link which triggers the lightbox. Also, be sure to hide the actual form element in css using it's ID

Eg:

```
#edit-field-somefield { display: none; }
```

The link should be something like this:

```
<a href="#edit-field-somefield" rel='lightbox'>Add more</a>
```

Hope this will help you get on the right track.

Comment: In my example above, that's what I'm trying to do.  The problem is that it displays the entire page, instead of the div.

Comment: I think you should get rid of `/screen ` and leave only the div ID in the link's href attribute

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to Marius Ilie, To create a link in the form you can use #item from the [form api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#item) like,

```
$form['snvisdt_note'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#title' => t('Add More Information'),
    '#markup' => l(t('note'), "javascript:void(0)", array('fragment' => '','external'=>true,'attributes' => array('rel' => 'lightbox' , ))),
    );
```

Comment: If I change my snvisdt_note item into an item from a textarea, how do I get the textarea field to show up?

Comment: you can have it as another form element

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for replace the href to the following `/screen  #div_id > *` that should do the job. I faced the same issue a while ago. (notice the spaces)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at [modal forms](https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms).

> Modal forms make use of the modal feature in the ctools module to open
> some common forms in a modal window.

Refer to some of the common forms already implemented like the login form.